# Call a function in angular service to return a new Promise

Tags: angular, typescript, azure-blob-storage

I want that the service.ts file return the name of the container and as well the contents of each blobs, which is stored on azure blobstorage.

but when im in the data.component.ts and want to call the service.ts modul it doesnt return blob.name at all. it return "account" and "sas" value.

```
export class DataComponent implements OnInit {
  @Input() title: string;
  //constructor() { }

  private jsondataService: JsonDataService;
  jsondata: JsonData[] = null;


  constructor(jsonService: JsonDataService) {
    this.jsondataService = jsonService;
  }

  ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jsondataService.getData().then(results => this.jsondata = results);
    console.log(this.jsondataService) // only return "sas" and "account" of the data.service.ts file
    
  }
```

Here is the data.service.ts file

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { environment } from '../../environments/environment';
import { JsonData } from '../models/jsondata';


import {
  BlobServiceClient,
  BlobDownloadResponseModel,
} from "@azure/storage-blob";



@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})

export class DataService {
  private account = "";
  private sas = "";

  constructor() {}
  

  getData(): Promise<JsonData[]> {


    const blobServiceClient = new BlobServiceClient(
     
      `https://${this.account}.blob.core.windows.net${this.sas}`,
    );

    return new Promise(resolve => {
      const containerName = "dataoutput";
      const containerClient = blobServiceClient.getContainerClient(containerName);
   
      

      //list blobs
      let i = 1;

      async function main() {
        i = 1;
        for await (const blob of containerClient.listBlobsFlat()) {
          console.log(`Blob ${i++}: ${blob.name}`);
          const blockBlobClient = containerClient.getBlockBlobClient(blob.name);      
          const downloadBlockBlobResponse  = await blockBlobClient.download(0);

          console.log(
            "Downloaded blob content",
            await streamToString(downloadBlockBlobResponse.readableStreamBody)
          );

        }

      }

      async function streamToString(readableStream) {
        return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
          const chunks: string[] = [];
          readableStream.on("data", (data) => {
            chunks.push(data.toString());
          });
          readableStream.on("end", () => {
            resolve(chunks.join(""));
          });
          readableStream.on("error", reject);
        });
      }

      main().catch((err) => {
        console.error("Error running sample:", err.message);
      });

    })

  }

}
```

I want that the dataservice.ts file return blobname and the contents of the readablestream to push to the frontend of the browser.

Somehow `readableStreamBody`is undefined.

I see that the error are show on browser console like this:

> data.service.ts:83 Error running sample: Cannot read property
> 'on' of undefined

See that the code section where you want to read the stream is something wrong.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
ngOnInit(): void {
    this.jsondataService.getData().toPromise()
     .then(results => this.jsondata = results);
    console.log(this.jsondataService);
  }
```

Comment: Hi Juany, i somehow got the error: Property 'toPromise' does not exist on type 'Promise<JsonData[]>'.

Comment: I figure out that the problem is when i want to read the content of the jsondata then the error comes on the browser console "data.service.ts:83 Error running sample: Cannot read property 'on' of undefined".

Comment: I solve that problem by  using "await downloadBlockBlobResponse.blobBody" cuz the downloaded the readablestream is only available in node.js. And then your edit with .toPromise() works fine! Thanks